# How to model django apps

Tags: django, django-models

i'm building a web app customer ticketing system using Django. i'm stuck and drawing blanks. accounts would create client, send email to sign up, and update tickets that clients create. clients would login and be able to create a ticket and view already created tickets. wondering if i should create my models all in app or so i create separate apps like accounts app, ticket app and client app. I've tried searching on google but unable to find a specific answer to my question. any help would be appreciated as i'm new to database modeling.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely up to you - it's your web app after all. But my suggestion would be to keep everything separate. The rule of thumb is - every app should have only one main thing that it does. For every app, can you describe what it's main purpose is? If you are listing more than one, then it's an indication that it should perhaps be a new app.

This might be of interest:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/reusable-apps/

Comment: Thank you for going easy on me and for answer my question! I'm still very new and not very good at asking the right questions or wording my questions the right way.